# Youtube video seems load fine on Mangific Popup for 1 second, but it auto-jumps to Youtube video page

Tags: video, youtube, magnific-popup

I've implemented magnific popup with standard code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.popup-youtube').magnificPopup({
      disableOn: 700,
      type: 'iframe',
      mainClass: 'mfp-fade',
      removalDelay: 160,
      preloader: false,
      fixedContentPos: false
    });
  });
</script>
```

It seems work well but..

The popup opens OK and for 1 second appear the video inside (only sometimes can see it) and instead of start playing inside the popup, the page reloads on Youtube video page :(

You can see the implementation on:

http://beta.clipsterapp.com/

Any idea, Dmitry? I make a lot of searchs, but no one has suffered exactly this particular issue..

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You could try to add `event.preventDefault();`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   $('.popup-youtube').magnificPopup({
     disableOn: 700,
     type: 'iframe',
     mainClass: 'mfp-fade',
     removalDelay: 160,
     preloader: false,
     fixedContentPos: false
   });
});
</script>
```